# 3 Questions on number theory.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have to everything using number congruences, and I am just a beginner, I know a few theorems, and we have to solve these using basics.

**1)** If $n=a^4$ where $a \in \mathbb Z$ then prove that $n \equiv 0,1,5$ or $6(mod \ 10)$.
My work: $a^4 \equiv x(mod \ 10)$
We have to find $x$.
But how to simplify the above congruence ?

**2)** Prove that $4n^2+4 \equiv 0(\mod \ 19)$ for any $n$.
But I think this question is wrong because it doesn't work for $1$ or $2$. I think it may be a misprint. It may be $\not\equiv$ in place of $\equiv$

**3)** Solve for $n$, $5n \equiv 3(mod \ 8)$.
Sol: $n \equiv -1(mod \ 8)$
So $n=8k-1$
Solution set becomes $\{...,-17,-9,-1,7,15,...\}$

Comment: Hint:  for #1. one attractive feature of modular arithmetic is that you tend to work with finite sets.  Trial and error often works!  #2 doesn't work for n = 0 either.   #3. you already got!

Comment: For #2 are you sure you weren't asked to show that the congruence was false for all n?

Comment: Dunno try it, (y)

Comment: To be clear:  I'm saying that, in fact, that congruence is false for all n (that is, there are no integers n which make it true).  Same hint applies.

Comment: Ain't there any more rigorous way than trial and error? Then they wouldn't have asked us to prove.

Comment: Trying all cases is perfectly rigorous.  There are general theorems that let you handle things like #2 but, if you don't know them already it's hard to imagine you were expected to work them out for these problems.

Comment: Then why does it tell you to **prove**?

Comment: Checking all cases is a proof!  There is some abstraction here...you have to  argue that checking each n from 0 to 18 is enough to make a conclusion for all n.    By the way, while there certainly are general theorems about this sort of simple congruence, there really aren't theorems that answer the question about general polynomial congruences (at least not very helpfully).  Those are often handled by trial and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:  Because we can write any number $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ as $a=10\cdot b + c$ with $b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ we see that $a^4 = (10 \cdot b + c)^4 \mod 10$. It is easy to see that this forms a polynomial with all terms except for the $c^4$ part is a multiple of $10$. Since we are working in $\mod 10$ we see that $a^4=(10 \cdot b + c)^4 = c^4 \mod 10$. This means we only have to look at the last digit of any number in $\mathbb{Z}$ and we are left with 10 cases:

1. Numbers ending on $0: 0^4=0$ so last digit is $0$.
2. Numbers ending on $1: 1^4=1$ so last digit is $1$.
3. Numbers ending on $2: 2^4=16$ so last digit is $6$.
4. Numbers ending on $3: 3^4 =81$ so last digit is $1$.
5. Numbers ending on $4: 4^4 =256$ so last digit is $6$.
6. Numbers ending on $5: 5^4 =625$ so last digit is $5$.
7. Numbers ending on $6: 6^4 =1296$ so last digit is $6$.
8. Numbers ending on $7: 7^4 =2401$ so last digit is $1$.
9. Numbers ending on $8: 8^4 =4096$ so last digit is $6$.
10. Numbers ending on $9: 9^4 =6561$ so last digit is $1$.

Thus we have the numbers $0,1,5,6$.

Question 2: 
$4n^2+4 = 0 \mod 19$ is not true, take $n=1$ and the result is trivial.

If we instead look at $4n^2+4 \neq \mod 19$ we see that we get a repeating pattern every 19 numbers. This can be seen by looking at \begin{align*}
4(n+19)^2+4 \mod 19 &= 4(n^2 + 38n + 19^2) +4 \mod 19 \\
&= 4 n^2 +4 \mod 19 + 38n \mod 19 + 19^2 \mod 19\end{align*} where the last 2 terms are obviously $0 \mod 19$.
You now have to compute the first 19 cases by hand (or excel/program it like I did), which shows indeed that $4n^2+4 \neq \mod 19$

Question 3: You have done this correctly.

Comment: But how to prove that we **will** not have any other numbers than those four? (1)

Comment: Because we can write any number $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ as $10*b +c$ with $b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ and because of this we see that $a^4=(10*b+c)^4 \mod 10$. This forms a polynomial with terms that are multiplied by 10 for all entries except for $c^4$. Because we are working with $\mod 10$ those all turn to $0$ and we only need to check the last digits.

Comment: @bof that is indeed slightly easier, however if you have a basic calculator available, it is enough to check this.